# Home screen icon for terminal program?

Tags: home-screen, terminal, scripts, bash

I'm using terminal-ide http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/ which is basically a terminal for android with all sorts of utilities. One is able to create bash scripts for example. Is there a way to create an icon on the home screen that will launch one of these scripts?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you might want to take a look at e.g. [GScript](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.rogro.GScriptLite), which claims to provide such shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create an icon on the home screen that will launch one of these scripts?

There is another way (other than [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113902/96277)) if you happen to use [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app. It allows a widget which can be used to execute a script.

1. Install that app, choose **Term Shortcut** widget in your current launcher.
2. Corresponding to **Arguments** enter:

   ```
   sh <FILEPATH>
   ```

   In my case, the query was:

   ```
   sh  /sdcard/airdroid/dd.sh
   ```

   As for the root access, you can either provide `su` access from inside the script and use the aforesaid command for execution, or do:

   ```
   su -c "sh  /sdcard/airdroid/dd.sh"
   ```

   Choice is yours!

   Choose icon or shortcut label as per your needs, tap **OK** and an icon would be placed on the home screen.
3. Tap the icon, the **Terminal Emulator** app window would open and the script would execute, just like in Desktop GNU/Linux.

We're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Terminal-ide doesn't appear to have that feature yet, but it does have an [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/issues/list) where you could request it. As it's an open-source program, you might even be able to add the feature yourself if you know (or are willing to teach yourself) a little about how Android apps are written.

Answer (score 0):

If the script isn't dependent on [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) but on shell only, then you can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to create a home screen shortcut which would execute the script.

Brief instructions:

1. Choose **Task Shortcut** widget in your current launcher.
2. Create a task name and tap `+`→ **Code → Run Shell**. Enter the details there as per your need.
3. Save the task, choose the icon, and a shortcut (icon) would be placed at home screen.
4. The shortcut would work as long as Tasker's service keeps running in background.

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager

worked for me , I made a favorite script and with add-on create a luncher to mount my ext4 USB pens  (with root) .