# Google Play Store only shows games

Tags: google-apps

Every time I load up the play store it only shows me games. Is there anyway to customize it so I see other apps besides games?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Google sets a periodical theme (e.g. New+Updated Games, New+Updated Apps, Mother's Day, etc), and the rest are based on your installation history. However, I never see Google showing games only on Play Store homepage. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I don't know how to get a screenshot of the store app. But basically it looks like this:

Top Scroller: games - 60% games

New + Updated Games - 100%  games

Recommended for you - 100% games

New + Updated Apps - 10% games

No WiFI? No Problem - 100% games

Games - 100% games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way of setting view preferences to a greater degree but you may be interested in launching the Play Store to directly show a collection (it wouldn't omit games). This command can help:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity -d "http://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/<collection_name>" --user 0
```

*<collection_name>* refers to a name of available collections. Per the document [Linking to Your Products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningCollection) the available collections are:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Collection                      collection_name    
----------------------------------------------------
Staff Picks (Featured)          featured
Editor's Choice                 editors_choice
Top Paid                        topselling_paid
Top Free                        topselling_free
Top New Free                    topselling_new_free
Top New Paid                    topselling_new_paid
Top Grossing                    topgrossing
Trending                        movers_shakers
Best Selling in Games           topselling_paid_game
-----------------------------------------------------
```

E.g.: to directly launch into Editor's choice, the command would be:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity -d "http://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/editors_choice" --user 0
```

As for launching the app a bit comfortably, you can use my answer available [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113902/96277). It would help you to setup a customized app shortcut for Play Store on home screen.

Answer (score 1):

Like Andrew said, there is no way to customise the homepage because Google sets the themes.

If you want personalised recommendations, it does that automatically if you scroll down the page (should see a 'recommended for you' tab.). This is dictated by what apps you have installed, previously installed and what's on your wishlist.

Another way of seeing only apps you like is by going onto the categories tab, and picking your favoured app category to browse.

^_^